# MySQL query with sub-select in IN()-clause gives not enough results

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I built a sql-query and don't get the results I expect. I try to explain what my steps to the sql-statement were.

First I have the sub-select that I use in the IN()-clause:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(job_id SEPARATOR ',') as job_ids
FROM candidate_job
WHERE candidate_id = 1111
GROUP BY candidate_id
```

The result is 1,7,37,38,39,135,136 and that's exactly what I expect.
Then I use these concenated numbers in my outer sql-statement:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(user_id) SEPARATOR ',') as user_ids
FROM user_job
WHERE job_id IN (1,7,37,38,39,135,136)
```

This gives me 139,539,1686,1759 and this is also exactly what I expect.

Now I combine both queries, the first one is the sub-select for the IN()-clause of the second one:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(user_id) SEPARATOR ',') as user_ids
FROM user_job
WHERE job_id IN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(job_id SEPARATOR ',') as job_ids
    FROM candidate_job
    WHERE candidate_id = 1111
    GROUP BY candidate_id
)
```

The result is only 139,539 and I don't understand why it's not 139,539,1686,1759 as it should be.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be the case? Use a GROUP_CONCAT() column in IN() shouldn't be so rare, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_concat()` gives you a comma-separated *string*; passing this as an operand to operator `in` does not do what you want (it ends up searching for an exact match).

I would recommend `exists`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(user_id) SEPARATOR ',') as user_ids
FROM user_job uj
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM candidate_job cj
    WHERE cj.candidate_id = 1111 AND uj.job_id = cj.job_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks man! I changed the 1 in the sub-select to job_id and now it works like a charm! :)

Comment: @Vencarii, Result of internal sub-select when used with exists clause, ignored by the query engine. So even if you write NULL instead of 1 or Job_id, It will produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The operator IN does not work with strings that are comma separated values.
What you want is [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id) as user_ids
FROM user_job
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(
        job_id,  
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(job_id) FROM candidate_job WHERE candidate_id = 1111)
)
```

`SEPARATOR ','` is not needed because `','` is the default separator.